Why always return length 0 object send to message main process to renderer process?
My program env: electron-vite+vue3
The problem occurs when I send a message from the main process to the renderer process.
In the main process, test the message delivery with webContents.send ('hi', 'hello') but in the renderer, only objects with length 0 always come out and the message 'hello' cannot be checked.
this is main/index.js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 900,
    height: 670,
    minHeight: 670,
    minWidth: 850,
    maxWidth: 1920,
    maxHeight: 1080,
    show: false,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    ...(process.platform === 'linux' ? { icon } : {}),
    webPreferences: {
      preload: join(__dirname, '../preload/index.js'),
      sandbox: false,
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
  ipcMain.handle('ping', () =>{
    return 'pong'
  })
  
  
  const plusCounter = (v) => v + 1
  
  ipcMain.handle('counter', async (event, v) => {
    const result = await plusCounter(v)
    console.log('result log: ', result)
    return result
  })


  
  mainWindow.on('ready-to-show', () => {
    mainWindow.show()
  })

  mainWindow.webContents.send('hi', 'hello')

  mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((details) => {
    shell.openExternal(details.url)
    return { action: 'deny' }
  })
  
  // HMR for renderer base on electron-vite cli.
  // Load the remote URL for development or the local html file for production.
  if (is.dev && process.env['ELECTRON_RENDERER_URL']) {
    mainWindow.loadURL(process.env['ELECTRON_RENDERER_URL'])
  } else {
    mainWindow.loadFile(join(__dirname, '../renderer/index.html'))
  }
}

this is preload/index.js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('test',{
  ping: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('ping'),
  plus: (value) => ipcRenderer.invoke('counter', value),
  hi: () => ipcRenderer.on('hi', (message) => message)
})

this is renderer
const func = async () => {
  const response = await window.test.ping()
  console.log('data is:', response)
  const hello = await window.test.hi()
  console.log('hello: ', hello)
}
func()

this is console log

where occur problem?
